# javascript/jquery loop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

I am trying to loop my function, but when I use it with setInterval it keeps looping i3-CTA and not the whole function.

```
window.onload = function start() {
    loop();
}

function loop(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#i3-content").delay(6500).fadeOut(function(){
            if ($('#i3-content').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#i3-CTA').fadeIn();
                $("#i3-CTA").delay(6000).fadeOut(function(){
                    if ($('#i3-CTA').is(':hidden')) {
                    $("#i3-content").fadeIn();
                    }
                });     
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I am still new with this but hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: Not much related but you didnt pass the `setInterval's` duration parameter, then you are delaying the functions 6.5s and again 6s, so it might have been executing after 6.5s and 12.5s, can you elaborate *it keeps looping i3-CTA*

Comment: What do you mean `it keeps looping i3-CTA and not the whole function`? There is no such function as `i3-CTA`

Comment: aah your right that is the problem I removed the 6.5 seconds and added it to the setInterval, but how can I make sure that my i3-CTA keeps showing for 6 seconds? because the delay only messes things up.

Comment: I mean the div I created that is called i3-CTA keeps fading in and out and not the whole function called loop()

Comment: you have to use closure to execute this one to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function start() {
     setInterval(loop(), 6500)
}

function loop(){
         debugger; 
        $("#i3-content").fadeOut(function(){
            if ($('#i3-content').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#i3-CTA').fadeIn();
                $("#i3-CTA").delay(6000).fadeToggle(function(){
                    if ($('#i3-CTA').is(':hidden')) {
                    $("#i3-content").fadeToggle();
                    }
                });     
            }
        });
   
}
```

```css
#i3-content{
height:20px;
  background:red;
}
#i3-CTA{
height:20px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='i3-content'></div>
<div id='i3-CTA'></div>
```

Comment: and now it needs to go back to green, so it keeps looping

Answer (score 0):

if we modify your code as below, it will be more meaningful:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    doSomeJob();
}

function doSomeJob(){
    console.log("first line of func")
    setInterval(function(){
       console.log("inside of setInterval")
        });
    }, 1000);
    console.log("last line of func")
}
```

then result will be like:

first line of func
last line of func
inside of setInterval
inside of setInterval
inside of setInterval
inside of setInterval
....

confusion coming from your function name loop.
setInterval gives you loop not calling function on window load